# How to SELECT data from one Table and INSERT into Another in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregate-functions

I have two collections:

#1: Items collection

```js
Items collection: [
  {
    _id: ObjectId("123abc"),
    itemNumber: 123456
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId("321cba"),
    itemNumber: 654321
  },
]
```

#2: Lists collection

```js
List collection: [
  {
    _id: ObjectId("456def"),
    items: ["123abc","321cba"]
  }
]
```

Currently my query works but is multi part due to my lack of understanding of the aggregate pipeline. This route accepts an array of itemNumbers from the client, $match'es them in the Item collection to $project their _id's, then flattens the array of item _id objects, and finally saves that array to the List collection.

In short, I am simply searching for the _id's of the numbers from the request array in the Items collection to be saved in a List array in the List collection.

```js
router.post("/", (req, res) => {
  const data = req.body.items; //[123456, 654321]

  Item.aggregate([
    {
      $match: {
        itemNumber: {
          $in: data,
        },
      },
    },
    {
      $project: {
        _id: 1,
      },
    },
  ])
    .then((res) => { //How do I make this a single aggregate pipeline query?
      new List({
        items: res.map((id) => {
          return id._id;
        }),
      }).save();
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
});
```

I need the aggregate query to flatten the array from the $matched Item collection results and store them all in one pipeline.

The $match results before they are flattened:

```js
[
  { _id: new ObjectId("123abc") },
  { _id: new ObjectId("321cba") },
]
```

Answer (score 0):

1. aggregate by `$group`
2. `items: res[0].items`

```
  Item.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      itemNumber: {
        $in: [
          123456,
          654321
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      "_id": null,
      "items": {
        "$push": "$$ROOT._id"
      }
    }
  }
])
    .then((res) => { 
      new List({
        items: res[0].items,
      }).save();
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
});
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/TbDww0tyD4y)

Comment: Thank you, but your answer is still a two part query. Your answer eliminated the map function but did not create a single aggregate query. In your answer, the server has to make two queries (eg. $match and .save()), but I need only one. Hopefully that makes sense.